# Automatically Update Work Item Status within Visual Studio (From 'New' to 'Active')

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, agile, kanban

Is there a way to automatically update the status of a Work Item within Azure DevOps from 'New' to 'Active' when the item is added to my 'In Progress Work' from within the 'Available Work Items' section of Visual Studio?

Brief context: I'm using the Kanban board within Azure DevOps and I'd like to move work items along the columns / stages in as automated a way as possible via Visual Studio.

This synchronisation seems to be working fine for items going from 'Active' to 'Resolved', e.g. when I add items to my 'In Progress', amend some code, and perform a check in, I can visually see the item move over to the next column of my Kanban board - it's also changing it's status from 'Active' to 'Resolved'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically update the status of a Work Item
>   within Azure DevOps from 'New' to 'Active' when the item is added to
>   my 'In Progress Work' from within the 'Available Work Items' section
>   of Visual Studio?

The status of the work items in Azure DevOps is not a one-to-one relationship with the work item status of My work in Visual Studio.

The status of work item in Visual Studio is used to classify the work items not change the status of the work item, so that we can more clearly distinguish which work items are being processed.

You can view the description of `In Progress Work` in Visual Studio is：

> drag a work item here **to get started**

This looks more like a swim lanes, giving developers a clearer idea of which workitems are associated with development.

Besides, when we commit the code and status of work items, there is option which we could select only with `Associate` and `Resolve`:

[image]

Only if we confirm that the currently associated work item is completed, we will choose the option to `Resolve`, otherwise it will be `Associate`.

On the other hand, we could add a custom status of work item on the Azure DevOps. Obviously, we could not match our new custom state to the status of work item in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.I appreciate that the statuses of Azure DevOps work items are distinctly different from VS - but wondered if there was a way to do this programmatically. 

I'm currently looking into Azure DevOps REST API 5.0 which seems to offer powerful ways of creating customisation within a project (in my cases, specifically around updating 'states'): [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/states/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Comment: @mitchil, Indeed, using REST API 5.0, we could update the statuses of Azure DevOps work items programmatically. But we have to work with the team explorer to get what you want. The  REST API could not work with team explorer, you have to invoke client API. It should be not easy(or not recommend) to complete it. You can submit your request to the Azure Devops dedicated forum:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.